# 500 internal server error mvc ftp publish method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-hosting

I have recently completed my application on mvc and would like to publish it using the FTP option.

As follows is my connection string:

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=41.76.116.92;Initial Catalog=OfficeWeb;User ID=######; Password=#########;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When using the FTP method when publishing, details are filled in as follows:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsLq5.png)

I keep getting a 500 internal error.

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

After playing around I now have this displayed on my screen. Any solutions or tips guys? It will be of great help

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYC1Z.png)

Comment: Do you get 500 internal server while loading your site ?

Comment: Yes sir, I did.

Comment: Did you find the reason why ? Or paste the error stack trace or screen shot ?